# convert string to date and format the date

Tags: java, android, date

I have String variable which contains date. Now how to display July 15 from that string variable? (for example 2012-07-15)

```
String strdate = "2012-07-15";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
try {
    d1 = formatter.parse(strdate);
    System.out.println(d1 + "---date first---");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: yes i am converting string to date and how can i display July 15 from date 2012-07-15? can you help me for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parsing template does not match your example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

(with `MM` instead of `MMM`).

To output July 15, you can use a second formatter:

```
SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");
System.out.println(output.format(d1)); //July 15
```

Comment: @user370305 actually both should work - in standard java, `MMM` outputs `Jul` while `MMMM` outputs `July` so I use the long version.

Answer (score 1):

Something like,

```
try {
  String strdate = "2012-07-15";
  DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"");
  DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");
  System.out.println(df2.format(df1.parse(strdate)+ "---date first---");
}
catch (ParseException e) {
 // Exception handling
}
```